# Setting frame size in Emacs on toggle out of fullscreen

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am using Carbon Emacs 23 and am trying to get the frame width to be a certain value after toggling out of a fullscreen frame (as set by a function). Actually, the weird thing is that not only is the width not set, but if you toggle out of fullscreen repeatedly the frame gets smaller and smaller, like a disappearing window. Appreciate any ideas, I have tried a few different ones. Here is the code:

```
    (defun set-frame-size-according-to-resolution ()                                                                                                     
  (interactive)                                                                                                                                      
  (if window-system                                                                                                                                  
      (progn                                                                                                                                             
        ;; use 120 char wide window for largeish displays                                                                                                
        ;; and smaller 80 column windows for smaller displays                                                                                            
        ;; pick whatever numbers make sense for you                                                                                                      
        (if (> (x-display-pixel-width) 1280)                                                                                                             
            (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist (cons 'width 140))                                                                                         
          (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist (cons 'width 100)))                                                                                           
        ;; for the height, subtract a couple hundred pixels                                                                                              
        ;; from the screen height (for panels, menubars and                                                                                              
        ;; whatnot), then divide by the height of a char to                                                                                              
        ;; get the height we want                                                                                                                        
        (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist                                                                                                                
                     (cons 'height (/ (- (x-display-pixel-height) 200) (frame-char-height)))))))                                                         


;;; This used to be in Carbon Emacs, puttin' it back in with my own twist
(defun mac-toggle-max-window ()
  (interactive)
  (set-frame-parameter nil 'fullscreen 
                       (if (frame-parameter nil 'fullscreen)
                           (progn
                             (scroll-bar-mode 1) ;; turn on scrollbars when not in fullscreen mode
                             (set-frame-size-according-to-resolution)
                             nil)
                         (progn
                           (scroll-bar-mode -1) ;; turn off scrollbars when in fullscreen mode
                           'fullboth)))) 

;;; Toggle full screen via CMD-Return (my meta key is mapped to command on OS X
(define-key global-map [(meta return)]
    'mac-toggle-max-window)
```

Answer (score 2):

Never mind, I figured it out a few minutes later.

Here is the answer:

```
;;; Set frame width - used on toggle out of fullscreen mode
(defun default-frame-width ()
    "Set width of selected frame."
    (modify-frame-parameters
     (selected-frame)
     (list (cons 'width 140))))

;;; This used to be in Carbon Emacs, puttin' it back in with my own twist
(defun mac-toggle-max-window ()
  (interactive)
  (set-frame-parameter nil 'fullscreen 
                       (if (frame-parameter nil 'fullscreen)
                           (progn
                             (scroll-bar-mode 1) ;; turn on scrollbars when not in fullscreen mode
                             (default-frame-width)
                             nil)
                         (progn
                           (scroll-bar-mode -1) ;; turn off scrollbars when in fullscreen mode
                           'fullboth)))) 

;;; Toggle full screen via CMD-Return (my meta key is mapped to command on OS X
(define-key global-map [(meta return)]
    'mac-toggle-max-window)
```